# Artifactory virtual RMP repo not working, but remote does work

Tags: artifactory

I currently have a few RPM remote repos pointing to different mirror paths.

One of my remote repos "centos-repo" points to:

```
http://mirror.centos.org/centos/8-stream/BaseOS/x86_64/os/
```

In my rpm.repo file I have:

```
[Artifactory]
name=Artifactory
baseurl=https://$user:$pass@re-artifactory.company.com/artifactory/centos-rpm/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
```

when I do the following in my docker image it works:

```
dnf install -y openssl
```

---

Now if I change my rmp.repo file to point to my virtual repo "rmp" like this:

```
[Artifactory]
name=Artifactory
baseurl=https://$user:$pass@re-artifactory.company.com/artifactory/rpm/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
```

my openssl download does not work.  It gives the following error:

```
#29 124.4   - Curl error (28): Timeout was reached for https://<user>:<pass>@re-artifactory.company.com/artifactory/rpm/repodata/repomd.xml [Operation too slow. Less than 1000 bytes/sec transferred the last 30 seconds]
```

The path in the error to the repomd file is now incorrect.  It is not able to properly point to what I have set in my remote repo.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is the Artifactory version you are using, however the issue you describe sounds similar to the public issue - [RTFACT-26309](https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-26309).

After looking into the mentioned issue, it seems that it is now resolved, however, the version it will be fixed with is not yet released. The fix should be delivered with one of the 7.37.x versions.

I hope this information helps.